# Parse multiple XML files to one list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a case that when parsing multiple XML files, actually I want the result of the parsing XML to become a single dictionary list instead of multiple dictionary lists.

```
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def open_xml(filenames):
    for filename in filenames: 
        with open(filename) as fp:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
        parse_xml_files(soup)


def parse_xml_files(soup):
    stringToListOfDict = []
    .
    .
    .

    for info in infos:
        dict = {} 
        
        types = info.find_all('type')
        values = info.find_all('value')
        
        for type in types:
            dict[type.attrs['p']] = type.text
      
        stringToListOfDict.append({'Date': Date, 'Time': Time, 'NodeName': node})
        for value in values:
            for result in value.find_all('x'):
                label = dict[result.attrs['y']]
                value = result.text 
                if label:
                    stringToListOfDict[-1][label] = value    

    print(stringToListOfDict)
 
def main():
    open_xml(filenames = glob.glob("*.xml"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With my code above, it always produces two dictionary lists (e.g. for two XML files) below:

```
[{'Date': '2020-11-19', 'Time': '18:15', 'NodeName': 'LinuxSuSe','Speed': '16'}]
[{'Date': '2020-11-19', 'Time': '18:30', 'NodeName': 'LinuxRedhat','Speed': '16'}]
```

The desired output should be one list with two dictionaries only:

```
[{'Date': '2020-11-19', 'Time': '18:15', 'NodeName': 'LinuxSuSe','Speed': '16'},{'Date': '2020-11-19', 'Time': '18:30', 'NodeName':'LinuxRedhat','Speed': '16'}]
```

Really appreciated your feedback

Comment: You are probably calling the funciton multiple times with different inputs? Hence, each time it will return (or print in your case) the list created during each call. If you really want to call the function with different inputs bu have a single final list the easiest way would be to set a global variable where you concatenate the returned list of each call. Something like `final_list += parse_xml_files(soup)`

Comment: Sample xml, enough to reproduce the problem would help.

Comment: you should learn to use `return` instead of `print()`. `print()` is used only it sends data on screen but it will not join then to one list. `return` can send from `parse_xml_files` to `open_xml` and then you can append it to global one list

Answer (score 0):

`print()` is used only to send information on screen and it will not join all results in one list.

Your name `parse_xml_files` is missleading because it parses single file, not all files. And this function should use `return` to send result for single file and in `open_xml` you should get this result add to one list - and then you should have all files in one list.

Not tested:

```
def open_xml(filenames):

    all_files = []

    for filename in filenames: 
        with open(filename) as fp:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
        result = parse_xml_file(soup)  # <-- get result from parse_xml_file
        all_files += result  # <-- append result to list 

    print(all_files)  # <-- display all results
    
def parse_xml_file(soup):
    stringToListOfDict = []

    # ... code ...

    for info in infos:
        dict = {} 
        
        types = info.find_all('type')
        values = info.find_all('value')
        
        for type in types:
            dict[type.attrs['p']] = type.text
      
        stringToListOfDict.append({'Date': Date, 'Time': Time, 'NodeName': node})
        for value in values:
            for result in value.find_all('x'):
                label = dict[result.attrs['y']]
                value = result.text 
                if label:
                    stringToListOfDict[-1][label] = value    

    #print(stringToListOfDict)

    return stringToListOfDict  # <-- send to open_xml
```